# When should I use the CPU or or the GPU compiler option in Flash?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I've read through [this section](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-4c2e64612754b0a95b-8000.html) of Adobe's excellent [10.1 optimization tips](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/index.html). I found the statement below to be very helpful. Is there anything else to look out for? Is the dumbed-down difference just: use the GPU for raster and CPU for vector graphics?

> The GPU is only effective for bitmaps,
>   solid shapes, and display objects that
>   have the cacheAsBitmap and
>   cacheAsBitmapMatrix set. When the GPU
>   is used in tandem for other display
>   objects and this generally results in
>   poor rendering performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just notice it that you want to run in GPU and not CPU by this line on your Manifest.xml

```
<renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
```

---

dan

Answer (score 0):

I would generally say that if you are going to make use of the new molehill api then gpu is a must, or if you are making a mobile application with any kind of animation then you should rasterize it and enable gpu mode.

Other than that, you probably wont notice too much difference from CPU mode on a standard desktop pc.

Answer (score 0):

See [GPU rendering in mobile AIR applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html).  Basically, if you need smooth animation of static DisplayObjects, want to take the time to optimize everything, and don't have video, use GPU.  Otherwise, use CPU.